# How to enable configuration translation on custom module

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I wrote a module where I using a form for editing my module's configs. My current goal to be able to translate some of my config field's values with configuration translation. I already implemented the followings:

- For the menus:

  - mymodule.links.menu.yml
  - mymodule.links.task.yml
- For the translation:

  - mymodule.config_translation.yml
  - config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml (I indicated also which should be translated and which shouldn't)

I also added language into my config, however, I don't think there's any meaning for it

My current problem is: when I going to my settings page, I go to the translate tab, add a language and that form is totally empty. There's no field listed where I can write anything, just a save button... what am I missing?

**config/install/mymodule.mymodulesettings.yml**

```
service_id: ''
normalized: true
success: 'Successfully subscribed!'
langcode: en
```

**config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml**

```
mymodule.mymodulesettings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'Mymodule settings'
  mapping:
    success:
      type: string
      label: 'Success message'
      translatable: true
    normalized:
      type: boolean
      label: 'E-mail address should be normalized?'
      translatable: false
    service_id:
      type: string
      label: 'Service id'
      translatable: false
```

**mymodule.links.menu.yml**

```
mymodule.mymodule_settings_form:
  title: 'Mymodule Settings'
  route_name: mymodule.mymodule_settings_form
  description: 'Configure Mymodule integration'
  parent: system.admin_config_system
  weight: 99
```

**mymodule.links.task.yml**

```
mymodule.mymodule_settings_form_tab:
  base_route: mymodule.mymodule_settings_form
  title: 'Mymodule Settings'
  route_name: mymodule.mymodule_settings_form
```

**mymodule.routing.yml**

```
mymodule.mymodule_settings_form:
  path: '/admin/config/system/mymodule-settings'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\MymoduleSettingsForm'
    _title: 'Mymodule Settings Form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'manage mymodule settings'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

**mymodule.permission.yml**

```
manage mymodule settings:
  title: 'Manage mymodule settings'
  description: 'Allows users to configure mymodule'
```

**mymodule.config_translation.yml**

```
mymodule.mymodule_settings_form:
  title: 'Newsroom Mymodule Form'
  base_route_name: mymodule.mymodule_settings_form
  names:
    - mymodule.mymodulesettings
```

Comment: What I learned so far from configuration translation is that you need at least one root property to be translatable in order to make nested keys to be translatable.

Comment: Also worth checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862690/drupal-8-translatable-configuration. TLDR; http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2014-may-26/drupal-8-multilingual-tidbits-16-configuration-translation-development

Comment: I don't have nested keys, all keys are in the same level and I viewing the site as user 1

Comment: If all your keys are root level, check the second link which show sytem.site connfiguration as an example of config translation. Also please improve your question by provinding your configuration schema, translation definition and links, that may help find way is not working form you.

Comment: I've added I think all the yml files which I created for this. Only the edit form is missing. I didn't change there anything. One more thing, I noticed that if I don'T say directly the `success` is `translatable: true`, then I don't have a translate tab.

Comment: I think I found the problem, on your schema change the type from `string` to `label` for those you want to be translatable. Also remove all translatable: false since its the default behavior. Also for `label` does not need the translatable key since also defualt. Check this http://hojtsy.hu/files/ConfigSchemaCheatSheet1.5.pdf

Comment: Yes, the `label` was the missing part. `langcode` is not required to schema I think, because the `config_object` contains it.

Comment: Yes you're right I removed my comments since I realize that :)

Comment: Send an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as commented above is the type of the translatable properties on the schema. Needs to be changed from `string` to `label` also the `translatable: false` can be safely removed since is default behavior, and also no needed for label or text types.

For more information about config translation check the [cheatsheet](http://hojtsy.hu/files/ConfigSchemaCheatSheet1.5.pdf).