# Translate configuration values in custom webform handler

Tags: 8, webforms, i18n-l10n

I created a Custom Webform Handler, which uses the email and name data from the form input to subscribe the user to a newsletter service through the vendors API.

Ich created a configuration form with this handler, where I can input the API key and the mailing list of the newsletter service.

This all works well up until the point where I want to translate the webform to a different language. I need to have a different configuration for the mailing list in German than in English.

I checked the code of the handlers that come with the webform module, but I can't figure out, how to define, which configuration field values should be translated. I need to have the `newsletter_list` form element to be translated.

Can anyone help?

This is my shortened code

```
<?php
/**
  * @file custom_webform_handler/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/NewsletterWebformHandler.php
  */
namespace Drupal\custom_webform_handler\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;

// ...
/**
 * ´Newsletter Webform handler.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "newsletter",
 *   label = @Translation("Newsletter Subscription"),
 *   category = @Translation("Subscription"),
 *   description = @Translation("Subscribe to Newsletter"),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_SINGLE,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_IGNORED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_REQUIRED,
 * )
 */

class NewsletterWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase
{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return [
      'newsletter_apikey' => '',
      'newsletter_list' => '',
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['newsletter'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Newsletter settings'),
    ];
    $form['newsletter']['newsletter_apikey'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('API key'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['newsletter_apikey'],
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];
    $form['newsletter']['newsletter_list'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Mailing List'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['newsletter_list'],
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];
    
    return $this->setSettingsParents($form);

  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
    // ...
  }

// ...
}
```

I read that I need to have a schema for doing this, so I tried adding one, but it didn't change anything

```
# file custom_webform_handler/config/schema/custom_webform_handler.schema.yml
webform.handler.newsletter:
  type: mapping
  label: 'Newsletter'
  mapping:
    newsletter_list:
      label: 'Mailing List'
      type: string
```

## Edit

To make it more clear:
I created a Handler that has this configuration form

[image]

The connection settings are the ones that need to be translated

When I go to the translation page of my webform, I can translate the Email-Handler settings, but not my custom Newsletter Subscription handler settings

[image]

Comment: You need to add a config_translation.yml ;) See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290475/how-to-enable-configuration-translation-on-custom-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did provide the wrong type. It should be `label` and not `string`

```
webform.handler.newsletter2go:
  type: mapping
  label: 'Newsletter2go'
  mapping:
    newsletter2go_formcode:
      label: Formcode
      type: label
```

Comment: damn oversaw that ;)

Comment: Yes, label is a string marked as translatable. Not very intuitive without reading the docs https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-schemametadata#properties

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add translations in /config/install/language/[langcode]/config.name.yml

so `/config/install/language/fr/custom_webform_handler.handler.newsletter.yml`

But the whole config translation of not really well supported/buggy, you need to make sure you're default language is EN! If not, [cli_language](https://www.drupal.org/project/cli_language) may help, cli language needs to be set to EN, and your module needs to be installed via cli (fe. drush).

---

**Update:**
To be able to translate your custom configuration you need to provide something, like a custom_webform.config_translation.yml:

custom_webform.newsletter_settings_form:
base_route_name: [not sure about the route ..]
names:
- webform.handler.newsletter

Dunno about which route to choose ... maybe entity.webform.settings_form

See also: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/language-config-translate.html

Comment: I don't know, if you understood the issue correctly. I don't want to add translations in the module itself. I want to enable the user to translate the value of the configuration fields.

Comment: I added two screenshot for clarification

Comment: See also here for the config_translation.yml - https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/language-config-translate.html